# What is the best place to ask questions about flowers

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Flowers caring related questions, specifically. Like "is rice water good for hyacinth plant?

I Google searched and I can't find single answer regarding the specific plant, and the rice water's benefit for plant seems debatable and answer varies.

Answer (score 9):

I would say that the [Gardening Stack Exchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) looks suitable.

Their help center has these listed as on topic:

- the general care and feeding of plants;
- gardening problems such as diagnosis and management of plant diseases and pests or methods for controlling weeds;
- identification of plants — trees, shrubs, flowers, wildflowers — cultivated or growing in the garden or as a houseplant, or of animals that are affecting your garden or houseplants;
- plant recommendations;
- garden or landscape planning and layout;
- the practice of gardening, including timing, tools and techniques.